# How to animate a circle which is drawn in OpenGL?

Tags: iphone, animation, opengl-es, popup, scale

I'm drawing several circles within my view by means of the drawRect function.

I'd like to have my circles pop up (scale to 1.2 -> scale to 1.0)

I've used coreanimation in the past but using OpenGL takes different functions.

Here's a snippit of my code which draws a circle in my view:

```
//calling draw function
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//setting a specific fill color
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0.0, 255.0, 0.0, 1.0);
//drawing the circle with a specific height, weight and x,y location
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(30 ,30, 20,20));
```

How can I animate this circle that it 'pops up'.

Comment: I see you are using CoreGraphics. In what way are you using OpenGL?

Comment: have you checked [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/12/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-9a.html)

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was using CoreGraphics, so this question is not appropriate. Any ideas of putting this for CoreGraphics.

Answer (score 0):

"Pops up" is not telling me that much.
if you want it to go from small to big modify width and height of rect.use a global int variable